Not Able to Use MVVM Cross and Firebase together in a DotNet 8.0 Android Project
While migrating from Xamarin.Android project to DotNet8 Android project, I need to use MVVMCross and Firebase Nuget packages together. If I use latest firebase packages directly in sample project then firebase initialises properly but when used in combination with latest MVVMCross packages, I am getting following error :
Error JAVA0000: Error in
"/Users/user/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm/1.4.4/buildTransitive/net8.0-android34.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class:
Type androidx.collection.ArrayMapKt is defined multiple times: /Users/user/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm/1.4.4/buildTransitive/net8.0-android34.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class, /Users/user/.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx/1.2.0.10/buildTransitive/net6.0-android31.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class
Compilation failed"
Currently used packages  :

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" Version="124.0.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics" Version="122.0.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Dynamic.Links" Version="122.1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Config" Version="122.0.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks" Version="118.2.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Core" Version="121.1.1.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" Version="118.5.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Common" Version="121.0.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Iid" Version="121.1.0.18" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" Version="118.4.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="MvvmCross" Version="9.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection" Version="1.4.4" />
</ItemGroup>

I need to use latest MVVMCross package.
1.MVVM Cross(9.2.0) and Firebase(Xamarin.Firebase.Config- 121.1.0.1) used with compatible Nuget package versions then firebase is not getting initialised.
2.Used latest firebase packages(Xamarin.Firebase.Config- 122.0.0.2) in DotNet8 android without MVVMCross then Firebase is getting initialised properly.
3.Latest firebase packages(Xamarin.Firebase.Config- 122.0.0.2) used with MVVMCross packages(9.2.0) then we are running into error as mentioned earlier.
4.To resolve ArrayMap Kit Error Have tried adding Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection but the issue is not resolved.
